# Problem involving Pigeonhole Principle

Tags: number-theory, pigeonhole-principle

I am trying to solve the following problem

Let $p$ a prime number, $r$ the largest integer less than $\sqrt p$ and a number $a$ such that $p \not \mid a$. Show that there exist two pairs $(m_1,n_1)$ and $(m_2,n_2)$ such that $0 \leq m_1,n_1,m_2,n_2 \leq r$ and $m_1 + an_1$, $m_2 + an_2$ have the same remainder when divided by $p$.

**My Attempt**
Let $A = \{m + an\ \mid 0 \leq m,n \leq \sqrt p\}$, we can see that $A$ has $(r+1)^2$ elements and then it will have the same number of remainders when divided by $p$. As $r < \sqrt p$ implies that $r^2 < p < (r+1)^2$. Since all remainders is less than $p$ by pigeonhole principle we have that there exists two pairs $(m_1,n_1)$ and $(m_2,n_2)$ such that $m_1 + an_1$, $m_2 + an_2$ have the same remainder when divided by $p$.

Note that I don't even use the fact of $p \not \mid a$ the reason is I don't know where I have to use this fact.

Thank you Guys

Comment: The hypothesis that $p \not \mid a$ is just to avoid some simple answers. Notice that if $p \mid a$ then the remainder of $m + an$ by $p$ is simply $m$, and you could pick any pair $(m, n_1)$ and $(m, n_2)$ with $n_1 \neq n_2$.

Comment: You use it to show that $(m_1,n_1)$ and $(m_2,n_2)$ really are distinct pairs. If $a\equiv 0\mod p$, this is just saying $m_1 = m_2$, so proving that they have the same remainder mod $p$ is meaningless.

Comment: So, in order to complete the proof is enough add up the case when $p \mid a$